# How google or facebook detects network connection availability in client

Tags: javascript, networking, internet-connection

For example i see in Gmail that if you lose internet connection it automatically shows a popup message that tells you that you don't have internet connection. And again it reconnects automatically if internet connection is back.

At the moment to detect internet connection availability i use ping-pong method. Basically i do HTTP ping requests every 10 seconds, and if ping is success i know that i have internet connection.

The problem is that i think that this is a little bit Hack'y to do ping requests every 10 second.

So, i'm wondering how google, or Facebook, or other big guys, do that? Thanks.

Comment: the keepalive polling is a common method, you can optimize it by sending requests only when no other requests are sent (when the user is not active)

Comment: read about webSockets

Comment: @Vidal, thanks, was thinking as well about web sockets, indeed gonna try that!